# User information not being saved

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I created a field in my signup form asking users for a link to their linkedin profile.

I created a page that returns a list of all the users (mentor users) and noticed that I cannot access the linkedin link. I am not sure if its because I have not saved the link or I am not accessing it correctly.

This is what I have in models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        post_save.connect(create_or_update, sender=User)
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user

#basic form
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

views.py (teachers.py)

```
class TeacherSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = TeacherSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'teacher'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
```

students.py (views)

```
#get list of mentors
def mentor_list(request):
    mentors = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True).select_related('mentor')
    template_name = 'classroom/students/mentor_list.html'
    context = {'mentors': mentors}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

the html where I generate the list of mentors:

```
                  <ul id="menu-header-menu">
                      {% for user in mentors %}
                          <li><a href="{{ user.mentor.linkedin }}">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a></li>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
```

From this list I only get the user's first and last name but cannot get their linkedin profile

Comment: I think problem is this. ".select_related('mentor')". What is "mentor"? You have not mentioned it in your model anywhere.

Comment: add related_name in Mentor model. try this and makemigrations/migrate. user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True, related_name='mentor')

Comment: The naming in your html is confusing.  It should be `{% for mentor in mentors %}<li><a href="{{ mentor.linkedin }}">{{ mentor.first_name }} {{ mentor.last_name }}</a></li>{% endfor %}`

Comment: @sandeep do you mind adding that as an answer, hard to follow as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use **mentor** in this line `mentors = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True).select_related('mentor')` but not defined **mentor** anywhere.

Table are connected with this line:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
```

add **related_name** .

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True, related_name='mentor')
```

Then makemigrations and migrate(I Hope you are familiar). Everything else is fine.

Also, print this to verify.

```
def mentor_list(request):
    mentors = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True).select_related('mentor')
    # Edited, remember this is just for checking. this is not required
    for user in mentors:
        try:
            print(user.mentor.linkedin)
        except:
             pass
    template_name = 'classroom/students/mentor_list.html'
    context = {'mentors': mentors}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: getting this error message ->  
User has no mentor.

Comment: have you added related_name and makemigrations + migrate after that?

Comment: classroom.models.User.mentor.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no mentor.

Comment: This is raising issue because 1 (or more) user don't have instance in Mentor model means not all users have linkedin id. I have edited the answer to check before printing. Please check edited answer after 2 min.

Comment: @Emm, you can check the answer